# How SVN store branch on the server?

Tags: svn, branch

I am trying to understand how Subversion stores branch code on the server side. Does it stores a diff of source based on commit id or replicate a source code in the branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SVNBook | Using Branches**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) tells us (check the "Cheap Copies" part):

> Subversion's repository has a special design. When you copy a
>   directory, you don't need to worry about the repository growing
>   huge—Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Instead, it
>   **creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree. If
>   you're an experienced Unix user, you'll recognize this as the same
>   concept behind a hard link.** As further changes are made to files and
>   directories beneath the copied directory, Subversion continues to
>   employ this hard link concept where it can. It duplicates data only
>   when it is necessary to disambiguate different versions of objects.

You may find SVNBook very helpful.

Comment: Thanks - It help me to understand.